# use DC power while plugged in without charging the battery?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, battery-life

I'm aware that keeping the battery fully charged is bad for the battery health. However, I often need to use my computer and it easily consumes a lot of battery power in a short time. (connected to an external display)

**Is there any way one can use the DC power without charging the battery, when keeping the power plug connected?**

I'm using a MacBook, but this applies to all laptops.

P.S. I'm only asking if there is such a mechanism to accomplish this, there's no need to comment on the battery per se or how to extend the battery life.

Comment: Are you on Windows ?

Comment: People debate the very thing that you say you are [aware of](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/matter-laptop-always-plugged-in-68480.html) as if it is a matter of fact.  I have a 2017 dell laptop, a 2017 macbook pro, and an HP business class i7 from around 2018 that I keep plugged in close to 100% of the time and I still seem to pull full battery life out of them when unplugged.  There is a chip that senses when the battery is full and simply doesn't supply more power to it.  I am not saying that I am correct, I am saying it is a matter of debate.

Comment: As @SeñorCMasMas states, more damage is done to the battery by frequent charge and deep discharge than by leaving it on charge all the time. Some specific laptops have mechanisms to limit charge, perhaps to 80%: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-limit-battery-charge-in-windows, and others do not. Trying to implement your own scheme is likely to *shorten* battery life.